# byte[] to String returns different String

Tags: java, android, string, encryption, arrays

For a given byte[], always the same, I'd like to get the corresponding String. the `byte[] result` has always the same value.

However the String returned is never the same, each time I launch my app the result changes.

```
byte[] results = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));

String result = Base64.encodeBase64String(results);
```

I tried several other ways to get my String like `String result = new String(results, "UTF-8");`, with `Array`,... but it remains different everytime.

This is happening after a cipher encryption. Here is the full code:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5padding");
byte[] keyBuf= new byte[16];

byte[] b= key.getBytes("UTF-8");
int len= b.length;
if (len > keyBuf.length) len = keyBuf.length;

System.arraycopy(b, 0, keyBuf, 0, len);
SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBuf, "AES256");


byte[] ivBuf= new byte[16];
            //IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBuf);
IvParameterSpec ivSpec=null; 

cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec);

byte[] results = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));

String result = Base64.encodeBase64String(results);
return result;
```

How can I ensure that the String "result" will remains the same?

Comment: Is the byte array different every time?

Comment: No, as precised the byte array remains the same.

Comment: What is `Base64`? Do you have a link to its documentation?

Comment: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;   https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html.  Note that I adapted the jar to fit with android and avoid conflicts.

Comment: That should work (I was wondering if it was calling `toString` on the array, which might cause this problem, but it doesn't). Can you provide ideally at least two samples of the `results` byte array and `result` string so people/I can see what the difference is?

Comment: Why aren't you just using the Base64 class which is part of Android? (Not that the base64 conversion is the problem here - it's the crypto code...)

Comment: The code you've given has another problem - you're asking for just "AES" as the cipher, but creating an AES256 key. That doesn't work - at least not on my machine. Creating a key with "AES" works - and then providing an IV spec with the same IV bytes each time gives the same result each time.

Comment: @JonSkeet I made some changes on the jar to be able to use it using jarjar, I finally import it using import android.org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64; . I had troubles using the native android one... Concerning the AES, I'll change it as well. However at the moment it's working without problem on my computer. EDIT: switching to AES works like a charm, i'll keep this one.

Comment: What problems did you have using the native Android Base64 class? I would try that again rather than going to great lengths to use a third party one...

Comment: encodeBase64String method was not found using native Android one. Then including org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64 was leading to runtime exception coming from a class error.

Comment: Please don't post solutions into the question body. This only confuses future readers. Just post it as an answer yourself.

Comment: The point was just to inform the reader that the error here doesn't correspond to the question's title, after further investigation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a different IV every time you encrypt - therefore you'll get different ciphertext each time you encrypt, too. Your `results` byte array is different each time, therefore the base64 representation is different.

If you really want to get the same result each time you encrypt the same input, you'll need to use the same IV each time... but be aware that that will reduce the security significantly. (Note that currently you're not even doing anything with `ivSpec`. You would probably want to pass it as a third argument to `Cipher.init`... but you'd want to do it having initialized it with an IV, not just using `null`.)

Comment: But as IvParameterSpec is set to null, then it should be the same every time right? Also using a Log, it appears that byte[] results.toString() is always the same.

Comment: @Virthuss: No, because a) you're not using it anyway, and b) I'd expect null to mean "generate a new one". Calling `toString()` on a `byte[]` doesn't indicate the data in it, either - if that's what you've been relying on to determine that the results are the same, you should ask yourself what representation you think you're seeing. Try dumping out each byte in `results` instead...

Comment: How can I ensure that the IV will remains the same then? Assigning it a fixed byte[] or a null and adding it as a third parameter doesnt prevent the final result to change...

Comment: @Virthuss: Well if you'd posted a short but *complete* example, it would be easy for me to test that assertion. I suspect that if you initialize it with a fixed byte array, then you *will* get the same results... but going from what you've posted to a complete program to demonstrate that would take a little while. If you edit the question to make that easier, it'll be easier to help you... See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I was thinking the String changed was coming from Base64, but it appears that the way I was checking my byte[] value was not the best one as there is in fact some difference in it each time. So the real problem was in fact the IV as you mentioned and the bad way I was using it... Thanks a lot! :)